# jQuery - off() and on() inside handler function

Tags: jquery, events

I use jQuery `.on()` method to attach event handler function to all div elements inside another div element with id "w1" but inside event handler function I want to detach that event before ajax call and attach it again after ajax is complete. Here is a simple script

```
$(document).on("click", "#w1 div", function() {
    $(document).off("click","#w1 div");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: "chtr.py",
        complete: function(){
            $(document).on("click","#w1 div"); //  does not work
        } 
    });
});
```

I don't know how to reattach event handler function to those elements again.

Comment: Sorry if stating the obvious, but in the complete you bind to #headnav instead of #w1?

Comment: Is the missing of `"` in `POST` a typo? Or is it the problem? Anyway `on` wants a third parameter which is the function to call after binding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to attach the same function, you'll need to make it a named function so you can refer to it again (or you could assign it to a variable):

```
$(document).on("click", "#w1 div", clickHandler);

function clickHandler() { 
    $(document).off("click","#w1 div");
    $.ajax({
          type: POST,
          cache: false,
          url: "chtr.py",
          complete: function(){
                $(document).on("click","#w1 div", clickHandler); 
           } 
    });
}
```

Comment: There is a typo, last should be: $(document).on("click","#w1 div", clickHandler);

Comment: @roasted: Yep. Morning coffee hasn't quite kicked in yet. Fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe you should just use `jQuery.one`:

http://api.jquery.com/one/

> Description: Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The
>   handler is executed at most once per element.

```
$("#foo").one("click", function() {
  alert("This will be displayed only once.");
});
```

So your code might look like this:

```
var ajaxHandling = function() {
    $.ajax({
          type: POST,
          cache: false,
          url: "chtr.py",
          complete: function(){
             $(document).one("click", "#w1 div", ajaxHandling); 
           } 

    });
 }
 $(document).one("click", "#w1 div", ajaxHandling);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use a **FLAG** for this:

```
$(document).on("click", "#w1 div", function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data('in-progress')) {
        return false;
    }

    // set the flag to prevent furthur clicks
    $this.data('in-progress', true);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        url: "chtr.py",
        complete: function(){
            // here ajax is completed
            // set the flag back
            $this.data('in-progress', false);
        } 
    });
});
```

---

- Open the `console` and check this [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/kYNrC/).